# wpf c# hide listview up/down scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ListView with 10 ListItems which I create in code-behind like all my controls.  By default, ListView adds a vertical scrollbar when there is insufficient space to show all 10 listItems.  I would like to hide this scrollbar, and simply use up down arrow keys to change selection, but I cannot find a way to 'switch it off'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView can scroll items because it has ScrollViewer element inside Template. By default scroll is Hidden, meaning that it appears when items exceed total Width/Height of ListView.

To disable scroll completely set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` attahed property to "Disabled"

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Comment: Yes and in code behind:              ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility(myListView, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);

Comment: @Petey, this method is a part of an attached DP registration. Inside it is setting a DP value like any other DP: `myListView.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);`. It is type-safe though. source can be found here: [SOURCE](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ScrollViewer.cs,549)